# Masanry layout in overlapping on the frontend

Tags: elementor, masonry

I am using elementor with the premium addons i am showing the Pinterest feeds but on the frontend the feeds items are overlapping in the masonry layout

it works when i assign a fix height to the items but when i set auto height then it show overlapping